# How to receive all combinations of all columns?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to get all row combinations of all columns (say 8 columns).  The following vba macro can do that but I get an error that says data overload:

```
Option Explicit

Const sTitle        As String = "shg Cartesian Product"

Sub CartesianProduct()

' shg 2012, 2013
' Choose one from col A, one from col B, ...

Dim rInp        As Range
Dim avInp       As Variant  ' ragged input list
Dim nCol        As Long     ' # columns in list
Dim rOut        As Range    ' output range
Dim iCol        As Long     ' column index
Dim iRow        As Long     ' row index
Dim aiCum()     As Long     ' cum count of arrangements from right to left
Dim aiCnt()     As Long     ' count of items in each column
Dim iArr        As Long     ' arrangement number
Dim avOut       As Variant  ' output buffer

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set rInp = Range("rgnInp")
If VarType(rInp.Value) = vbEmpty Then
    MsgBox Prompt:="No input!", _
           Buttons:=vbOKOnly, _
           Title:=sTitle
    Exit Sub
End If

Set rInp = rInp.CurrentRegion
If rInp.Columns.Count < 2 Or rInp.Rows.Count < 2 Then
    MsgBox Prompt:="Must have more than one row and more than one columns!", _
           Buttons:=vbOKOnly, _
           Title:=sTitle
    Exit Sub
End If

With rInp
    .Style = "Input"
    avInp = .Value
    nCol = .Columns.Count
    Set rOut = .Resize(1).Offset(.Rows.Count + 1)
    Range(rOut.Offset(-1, -1), Cells(Rows.Count, Columns.Count)).Clear
End With

ReDim aiCum(1 To nCol + 1)
ReDim aiCnt(1 To nCol)
aiCum(nCol + 1) = 1

For iCol = nCol To 1 Step -1
    For iRow = 1 To UBound(avInp, 1)
        If IsEmpty(avInp(iRow, iCol)) Then Exit For
        aiCnt(iCol) = aiCnt(iCol) + 1
    Next iRow

    aiCum(iCol) = aiCnt(iCol) * aiCum(iCol + 1)   <------ This is where it says error is
Next iCol

If aiCum(1) > Rows.Count - rOut.Row + 1 Then
    MsgBox Prompt:=Format(aiCum(1), "#,##0") & _
                   " is too many rows!", _
           Buttons:=vbOKOnly, Title:=sTitle
    Exit Sub
End If

ReDim avOut(1 To aiCum(1), 1 To nCol)
For iArr = 1 To aiCum(1)
    For iCol = 1 To nCol
        avOut(iArr, iCol) = avInp((Int((iArr - 1) * aiCnt(iCol) / aiCum(iCol))) Mod aiCnt(iCol) + 1, iCol)
    Next iCol
Next iArr

With rOut.Resize(aiCum(1), nCol)
    .NumberFormat = "@"
    .Value = avOut
    .Style = "Code"
    .Cells(1, 0).Value = 1
    .Cells(2, 0).Value = 2
    .Cells(1, 0).Resize(2).AutoFill .Columns(0)
End With

ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = False
rOut.EntireColumn.AutoFit
ActiveSheet.UsedRange
Beep
End Sub
```

Is there away to adjust for this? I also want it to not bring back the same values for a row. So lets say that two columns had the exact same data. If column A has lets say Ice cream, cake, and cookies and so does Column B, I don't want Row 1 to have cookies in column B if it is already picked in Column A.

Comment: it will help us if you edit your question to tell us which line the overload error occurs on.

Comment: sorry it is the line that has <-------- This is where error occurs

Comment: aiCum(iCol) = aiCnt(iCol) * aiCum(iCol + 1)

Comment: How many rows and columns are you working with? If `rows^columns` > 2^20 you run out of room.